# in while loop scanf gets skipped second time

Tags: c, while-loop

Well I am new to programming. I have problem with my code. In first run it works fine, but in second run it skips scanf and comes out of loop while debugger shows ch is still y and one more thing debugger shows is that in second iteration it does not reach to scanf. And even if the scanf gets skipped, why does control comes out of loop as value of ch has not changed. Kindly help me out.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char ch=y;
        while(ch==y || ch==Y)
        {
        printf("Its hello again to check\n");
        printf("Do you wish to continue: y or n\n");
        scanf("%c", &ch);
    }
    exit(0);
    }
```

And if I modify this code again like below
        #include

```
    int main()
    {
        char ch=y;
        while(ch==y || ch==Y)
        {
                printf("Its hello again to check\n");
                printf("Do you wish to continue: y or n\n");
                scanf("%c", &ch);
                //fflush(stdin);
                printf("Choice entered %d \n", ch);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
```

It then last printf gets skipped even if I use fflush.

Comment: Try changing your `y` and `Y` to `'y'` and `'Y'`

Comment: the input buffer doesn't clear itself... that's what the problem is here. There's enough duplicate questions on this matter, a quick google search would've answered this question before you even wrote it up

Comment: Use a debugger or after `scanf("%c", &ch);`, add `printf("%d\n", ch)` to see what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you press enter after giving the input, this is consumed by your scanf which is accepting a char (as pressing enter also results into char)

Adding a space before %c will solve your problem, Like :

```
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

Or, put a `getchar()` after `scanf()`

Cleaned :

```
 #include<stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char ch='y';
        do {

        printf("Its hello again to check\n");
        printf("Do you wish to continue: y or n\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        }while(ch=='y' || ch=='Y');
    }
```

Comment: this code worked the way I wanted to but I was willing to know why I was coming out of loop even scanf was skipped.

Comment: #include<stdio.h>

        int main()
        {
         char ch=y;
         while(ch==y || ch==Y)
         {
         printf("Its hello again to check\n");
         printf("Do you wish to continue: y or n\n");
                scanf("%c", &ch);
                printf("%c \n", ch);
         }
         exit(0);
        }

When I use this code it also work as I wish but in this case last printf function gets skipped.

Comment: What's the problem with the code which I've posted?

Comment: The last printf isn't getting skipped, it is printing a whitespace, which was stored in `ch` when you pressed enter key.