# Issue with gets function used with an structure in an loop

Tags: c

Here the `gets` function is not advancing as the `i` is increasing from 0 to 3. I want to store data for 3 `emps`, but when the `for` loop started it takes the `gets` statement takes the input but as `i` increases 1,2 the gets function is not taking the input the next line of code is displayed without execution of `gets` statement.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   struct emps
   {
       char name[20];
       char lic_no[10];
   };
   int main()
   {
       struct emps e[3];
       int a;
   
       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
           printf("enter your name\n");
           gets(e[i].name);
           printf("enter the license number\n");
           scanf("%s", &e[i].lic_no);
       }
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22226529/program-doesnt-execute-gets-after-scanf-even-using-fflushstdin etc.

Comment: can you plz tell me where I am wrong why the gets function is not executed alon with the loop

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-the-buffer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366509/input-in-c-scanf-before-gets-problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629256/in-while-loop-scanf-gets-skipped-second-time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59994428/scanf-with-the-space-after-d-not-working-before-gets

Comment: Don't use `scanf("%s"...` with `gets()`.  Best to use `fgets()` for input and then lop off the `'\n'`.

Comment: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/995714)